# How does the Planer move plugin work?

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the build a omni-directional robot in gazebo. I got it working model by applying forces to each wheel following [this](http://www.romin.upm.es/wiki/index.php?title=ROS%3ATutorials/Build_Your_Own_URDF_Robot) tutorial. But the problem is that I also need to do odometry, which I cannot do controlling the model this way.
I want to do path planning and navigation.

I cam across [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/212889/gazebo-planar-move-plugin-for-omni-directional-wheel/?answer=220467#post-id-220467) but I do not understand how I use it. Do I still control each wheel individual by setting commands to each wheel use the \cmd_vel topic? Or Do I ignore the individual wheel speeds and just use the /cmd_vel for the velocity of the robot? I have been stuck on this for a while

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223622/how-does-the-planer-move-plugin-work?/) by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2016-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usual way in path planning and navigation is to create velocity commands for the full robot. You usually apply the velocities to the `base_link` frame.

Then, you need a base controller which computes the given wheel velocities given the "full robot velocity" depending on you kinematics.
Thus, the `/cmd_vel` topic usually goes into the base controller, which then computes the wheel velocities.

Once you have the kinematic model of the robot, which you require to compute the command velocities for each wheel, you can use the inverse of this to compute the odometry from the current wheel velocities and then [publish the odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) to the ROS system.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on 2016-01-10**:
thank you,